# Concatenate rows based on multiple column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, concatenation, aggregate-functions

I am trying to get a new column with a concatenation of all distinct row values. This aggregation would be based on other columns.

[image]

I have tried the following but I get the same values repeated in the new column (A1, **A1,** A4). I need the concatenation to be distinct.

```
SELECT
    STRING_AGG(COLUMN1, ', ') AS COLUMN1_ALIAS
    ,COLUMN2
    ,COLUMN3
    ,COLUMN4
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY COLUMN2 ,COLUMN3 ,COLUMN4
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Produce DISTINCT values in STRING\_AGG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51646385/produce-distinct-values-in-string-agg)

Comment: I would still like to keep all my rows. I can not group. In that example: I want the first row  to say bird, but also dog,bird.  # Of Types  does not work; I want the value, not an aggregate. but thanks for the clue

Comment: Please use [edit] to create a [mre].   I have no clue where `bird` and `dog` are coming from....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want windowing rather than aggregation. Unfortunately, `string_agg` does not support `over()` in SQL Server ; neither does it support `distinct` in its aggregated form.

We could work around it with subqueries ; it is probably more efficient to deduplicate and pre-compute the aggregates first, then `join` with the original table:

```
select t.*, x.column1_alias
from mytable t
inner join (
    select column2, column3, column4, string_agg(column1, ', ') as column1_alias
    from (select distinct column1, column2, column3, column4 from mytable) t
    group by column2, column3, column4
) x on x.column2 = t.column2 and x.column3 = t.column3 and x.column4 = t.column4
```

Side note : in a database that supports both `over()` and `distinct` on string aggregation, the query would phrase as:

```
select t.*, 
    string_agg(distinct column4, ', ') 
        over(partition by column2, column3, column4) as column1_alias
from mytable t
```

Comment: You made my day sir. first option works perfect.