# How to delete duplicates after STRING_AGG?

Tags: c#, sql, duplicates, azure-sql-database, string-aggregation

First of all i've to tell you that i'm a beginner in `SQL`.

I want to select all the informations related to my PLAN thanks to it's id to put them in a `DataGridView` in my C# program.

We can affect multiples `voltage levels`, `catenary types` etc... to this plan and it would be stored in a table called `plans_into_voltage` and `plans_into_type` there.

So when I try to selecet all the informations related to a plan, if it has multiple voltage and/or many catenary types, it would duplicate rows like this :

[image: results example]

Then I tried to `STRING_AGG` but now I have duplicates into the row and I don't know how to avoid that/remove them..

This is my query :

```
SELECT TOP 20 pinfos.id
     , STRING_AGG(pinfos.plan_name, '|') 
     , STRING_AGG (voltage.name, '|') AS vname 
     , STRING_AGG(catType.name, '|') AS catname
FROM [allocation_schematic.information].primary_infos pinfos
     LEFT JOIN [allocation_schematic.types].plans_into_type pit 
            ON pinfos.id = pit.id_plan
     LEFT JOIN [allocation_schematic.types].catenary_type catType 
            ON pit.id_type = catType.id
     LEFT JOIN [allocation_schematic.types].plans_into_voltage pot 
            ON pinfos.id = pot.id_plan
     LEFT JOIN [allocation_schematic.types].voltage voltage 
            ON pot.id_voltage = voltage.id
GROUP BY pinfos.id
```

[image: Results]

But i want it like:

[image: this]

I've already check [this first solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51646385/produce-distinct-values-in-string-agg) and [this second one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48985732/how-to-avoid-duplicates-in-the-string-agg-function) but I don't understand how to implement it with my query.

Could someone help me with this please ? I've been on this trouble since 2 days..

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about try this query:

```
SELECT TOP 20 pinfos.id
    , STRING_AGG(pinfos.plan_name, '|') 
     , STRING_AGG (voltage.name, '|') AS vname 
     , STRING_AGG(catType.name, '|') AS catname
FROM (
    SELECT  DISTINCT pinfos.id 
                    pinfos.plan_name,
                    voltage.name,
                    catType.name
    FROM [allocation_schematic.information].primary_infos pinfos
     LEFT JOIN [allocation_schematic.types].plans_into_type pit 
            ON pinfos.id = pit.id_plan
     LEFT JOIN [allocation_schematic.types].catenary_type catType 
            ON pit.id_type = catType.id
     LEFT JOIN [allocation_schematic.types].plans_into_voltage pot 
            ON pinfos.id = pot.id_plan
     LEFT JOIN [allocation_schematic.types].voltage voltage 
            ON pot.id_voltage = voltage.id
)
GROUP BY pinfos.id
```

This query is modified accordding this statement:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(data)
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT FROM ...
)
```

I tested with my table and it works.

All data in my table employee:
[image]

Run my demo query:

```
SELECT emp.deptno, STRING_AGG(emp.ename,',') AS ename from (
    SELECT DISTINCT ename, deptno  FROM employee) as emp
GROUP BY emp.deptno
```

[image]

**Update:**

This query does't work as expected.

But Congratulations that you have solved it:

Used multiple queries and joined them thanks to a Dictionary in my c# Program and it works fine now

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think we're on the right way but I'm still having errors.

1) I had to add `AS ptest` between ')' and 'GROUP BY pinfos.id' because it was saying the syntax was incorrect. 

2) Now with the "correct" syntax i'm having the SQL error 4104 : The multi-part identifier "pinfos.id" could not be bound.

I tried some things with no success, maybe you'll see where is the problem.

Comment: I solved all the errors, the query looks like this now : https://pastebin.com/sDRCgQfh Unfortunately, it didn't work, i have the same results as before

Comment: Did you run the  `SELECT DISTINCT  pinfos.id AS planid,
                    pinfos.plan_name AS planname...` statement to test  if the duplicate values have been excluded?

Comment: Not really, i get [this](https://ibb.co/18KnLHb) when running the SELECT DISTINCT query only.

Comment: I guess this is caused by the more table left join. Maybe `SELECT DISTINCT` only work for one table, or try to change LEFT JOIN, test again.

Comment: Tried every kind of JOIN with no success. I thought to make an algorithm/function in SQL to delete between the delimiters what is exceeding. Do you think it's a good idea ?

Comment: All the examples we found  is worked for one table with duplicate value in row. Since  `SELECT STRING_AGG() FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT...)` doesn't work for your 4 table,   just try your new idea now. If the  algorithm/function works, that will  be very useful for us.

Comment: Sorry for replying late, I've tested some things (that didn't work) but I didn't have enough time to think about this function. So i just used multiple queries and joined them thanks to a Dictionary in my c# Program and it works fine now

Comment: @tsoich It doesn't matter. Congratulations that you have solved it !  I will update and add this to my answer, then others can know your problem solved know. Can you think about mark it as the answer?. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Done, thank you too. Maybe a user will find an SQL solution for this